# Java Error in Neo4j Rails Not Allowing Server to Start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j, neo4j.rb

I'm using Neo4j for my rails app. It was working fine a few days ago, but when I tried to start the server today, it wouldn't start. I checked out the log and got this error

> Exception in thread "Thread-11" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource@75ed6ed2' failed to stop. Please see attached cause exception.
>       at org.neo4j.helpers.RunCarefully.run(RunCarefully.java:57)
>       at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.stop(AbstractNeoServer.java:505)
>       at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper$1.run(Bootstrapper.java:181)
>   Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource@75ed6ed2' failed to stop. Please see attached cause exception.
>       at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.stop(LifeSupport.java:484)
>       at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.stopInstances(LifeSupport.java:165)
>       at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.stop(LifeSupport.java:147)
>       at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.state.DataSourceManager.stop(DataSourceManager.java:132)
>       at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.stop(LifeSupport.java:476)
>       at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.stopInstances(LifeSupport.java:165)
>       at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.stop(LifeSupport.java:147)
>       at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.shutdown(LifeSupport.java:188)
>       at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacade.shutdown(GraphDatabaseFacade.java:285)
>       at org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase.stop(LifecycleManagingDatabase.java:111)
>       at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.stop(LifeSupport.java:476)
>       at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.stopInstances(LifeSupport.java:165)
>       at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.stop(LifeSupport.java:147)
>       at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer$6.run(AbstractNeoServer.java:531)
>       at org.neo4j.helpers.RunCarefully.run(RunCarefully.java:47)
>       ... 2 more
>       Suppressed: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Failed to transition component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.pagecache.PageCacheLifecycle@6a82bc90' from STOPPED to SHUTTING_DOWN. Please see attached cause exception
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.shutdown(LifeSupport.java:515)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.shutdown(LifeSupport.java:203)
>           ... 9 more
>       Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot close the PageCache while files are still mapped:
>       neostore (1 mapping)
>       neostore.counts.db.a (1 mapping)
>       neostore.relationshipgroupstore.db (1 mapping)
>       neostore.schemastore.db (1 mapping)
>       neostore.labeltokenstore.db (1 mapping)
>       neostore.labeltokenstore.db.names (1 mapping)
>       neostore.relationshiptypestore.db (1 mapping)
>       neostore.relationshiptypestore.db.names (1 mapping)
>       neostore.relationshipstore.db (1 mapping)
>       neostore.propertystore.db (1 mapping)
>       neostore.propertystore.db.arrays (1 mapping)
>       neostore.propertystore.db.strings (1 mapping)
>       neostore.propertystore.db.index (1 mapping)
>       neostore.propertystore.db.index.keys (1 mapping)
>       neostore.nodestore.db (1 mapping)
>       neostore.nodestore.db.labels (1 mapping)
>           at org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.muninn.MuninnPageCache.close(MuninnPageCache.java:521)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.pagecache.PageCacheLifecycle.shutdown(PageCacheLifecycle.java:42)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.shutdown(LifeSupport.java:507)
>           ... 10 more

There's more, but is pretty repetitive. I'm not sure what this means. My log before this is clean with no errors. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What version of Neo4j?  Did your computer shut down unexpectedly or might you have killed the Neo4j process?  Neo4j should automatically fix such errors on startup, though.

Comment: I'm using version 6.1.0. I tried restarting my computer multiple times, but the error remains. When I run "rake neo4j:start" in my console, it says "Waiting for server to be ready...", but the server never actually starts.

Comment: This is a differently worded error message that is showing up: "ERROR Failed to start Neo4j: Starting Neo4j failed: Failed to transition component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.pagecache.PageCacheLifecycle@7e788982' from STOPPED to SHUTTING_DOWN."

Comment: 6.1.0 couldn't be your version of Neo4j.  Do you mean your version of either the `neo4j` gem or the `neo4j-core` gem?

Comment: To use Neo4j in embedded mode with jRuby you would need to also use either the `neo4j-community` gem or the `neo4j-enterprise` gem. The latest version of Neo4j that both of those allow is 2.2.x (there have since been 2.3 and 3.0 releases of Neo4j but we haven't updated the gems yet)

Comment: You might also try downloading the Neo4j server and copying (not moving) the database directory there (I think you would need to put the files under the `data/graph.db` folder).  Since you're probably not using a version of Neo4j greater that 2.2.x you would need to get the appropriate version of the server, which you can get here: http://neo4j.com/download/other-releases

Comment: This error also seems to be with Neo4j itself and not so much the gem, so I might check in on the public Slack group for Neo4j: https://neo4j.com/blog/public-neo4j-users-slack-group/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I've registered for the Slack channel. One other thing that might be of interest: I tried starting from scratch in a new rails project (neo4j 3.0). I am using the devise-neo4j gem. When I create a new user, the user shows up in the database, but cannot be recognized by the app. In the rails console, User.count -> 1, but User.first -> nil. Could this be a related issue?